# three js dont add AxesHelper on scene

Tags: three.js

I use three js version r146 https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/releases

And I try to add AxesHelper, like in documentation https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/helpers/AxesHelper

but I don't see new helper on me scene

```
export default class Viewer {

    axesHelper = new THREE.AxesHelper( 100 )

   ......

   addAxesHelper() {
        this.disposeAxesHelper()
        this.scene.add(this.axesHelper)
    }

   disposeAxesHelper() {
       this.axesHelper.dispose()
   }
}
```

after call method addAxesHelper I can see that axesHelper was addet in scene, but I dont see it

[image]

[image]

Comment: You put it inside your cube

Comment: I have a small box 
const box = new THREE.Mesh(
                new THREE.BoxGeometry(1,1,1),
                new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color : "grey"})
            )

Comment: @ЕвгенийРябышев Have you tried hiding your box?

Comment: Why are you disposing the `AxesHelper` before you add it?